# WSL2 Linux - Can't Launch Win-Kex in SL Mode

Tags: linux, windows-10, wsl2, seamless

## Environment

```
Windows build number: Windows 10 version 2004 build 19041
Your Distribution version: Kali 2020.3
Whether the issue is on WSL 2 and/or WSL 1: Linux version 4.19.128-microsoft-standard (WSL 2)
```

## Steps to reproduce

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install kali-win-kex
user@host:~$ kex --sl

        Checking /root/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-ipv4:0
        Enabling SL mode
        Waited 100 seconds for desktop, giving up
        Saving Win-KeX SL session
        Started Win-KeX SL
```

## Expected behavior

I would like the GUI environment to start on top of the Windows like here: https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex-sl/win-kex-sl.png

## Actual behavior

There is nothing happening. I have tried to use "-w" parameter also but after 100 (300) seconds the process is closed.
I can open Kali in Window Mode with `kex --win` but the SL Mode doesn't work.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Could be your Windows Firewall or other system firewall blocking the connection for vcxsrv.exe

https://medium.com/@jaredbeymer/win-kex-kali-linux-seamless-error-fix-5e758881fd3c

Comment: Thanks for a good answer to a problem which is probably a pain for those being affected, and welcome to SU. You eventually should have written a sentence or two about what security implications your solution has (i.e. restrict access to vcxsrc.exe as far as possible, e.g. to localhost, and so on). I am writing this because your answer is currently on the review queue and I am reviewing it. However, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem and the solution was simple. It's a permission problem. Run kex via superuser-do (`kex --sl`). I wonder if you ever find this answer, you asked the question overe 2 years ago. Hope this still helps the others to tackle the issue!